# Django can't connect to MariaDB instance with Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I am getting the following error: `(2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")`,
when trying to use the Django admin dashboard (or running migrations or anything that connects to the DB).

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    db:
        image: mariadb
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql
        env_file:
            - .env
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        healthcheck:
            test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=test --password=test --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
            interval: 3s
            timeout: 1s
            retries: 5

    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 web.wsgi
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_healthy
```

`.env` contains all `MYSQL_*` env variables for the server: root password, user, database name and password. It also contains env for my `settings.py`, which looks like this:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME', 'test'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER', 'test'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', 'test'),
        'HOST': os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

For the example here, `DB_HOST` is set in `.env` to **db**, which is the image name in `docker-compose.yml`. If I jump into a bash shell of my web app, I can `ping db`, so it can see the mariadb container (they're on the same network).

Whenever I try to use `mysql` in the **db** container though (`mysql -u root -p`) it gives me this error:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Port 3306 is exposed from the **db** container, the container also waits for the healthcheck, yet something is missing.

Log for the mariadb container (`docker-compose logs --tail="all" db`):

```
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.9+maria~focal started.
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.9+maria~focal started.
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:53 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.9-MariaDB-1:10.5.9+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:53 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 32190)
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:53 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 151 (was 151)  table_cache: 421 (was 2000)
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.9 started; log sequence number 45514; transaction id 20
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210413 16:48:54
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@26b39369ed70' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
db_1            | 2021-04-13 16:48:54 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1            | Version: '10.5.9-MariaDB-1:10.5.9+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

So.. what am I missing here? This is how all the tutorials look like, yet it doesn't work for me. I am using moby-engine on Fedora 33.

Comment: Replace `localhost` with `db` in `HOST` variable to see if connection works

Comment: That's what I have set up in my .env file, `DB_HOST=db`, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Run `docker ps -a` and make sure database container is running, or see the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was (probably) in SELinux denying the connection, anyway adding this to all services fixes the problem:

```yaml
security_opt:
    - label=type:container_runtime_t
```

This affects moby-engine at least on Fedora 33 and 34 from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the `mysql` command is trying to connect to a socket file at `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. But the MariaDB server in Docker is not configured to expose that file. You need to use the `-H localhost` option to tell it where to connect to. That way it will actually connect to the TCP/IP socket instead of the filesystem one.